# adjust the height of the div automatically based on the content inside

Tags: html, css

I want to adjust the height of div content automatically without setting fixed height of main div, but I'm not sure how. I tried with `height:100%` and `height: auto`

This is my code:

```css
 .tmr_box {
     height: 470px;
}
 .tmr_inner {
     position: fixed;
     width: 100%;
     max-height: 440px;
     overflow-x: hidden;
     white-space: nowrap;
     height: auto;
     overflow-y: auto;
     max-width: calc(40% + 110px);
}
```

```html
<form>
    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px;">
        <div class="col-md-6 tmr_box" ng-if="vm.tmr">
            .....
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 tmr_box" ng-if="vm.tmr">
            <table>
                ...
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Without fixed height property, it looks like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXgM2.png)
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Welcome to SO, please consider using the code snippet to include HTML and CSS, instead of only pasting CSS, so that readers can easily view your code and help.

Comment: I've added short html code, there's bunch of non-important angular code, i hope this helps

Comment: where you use the 
 .tmr_inner ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem comes from the `position:fixed` of the div's content (`.tmr_inner`). Because of it the parent div render without paying so much attention to him. You should try to remove this property or add it to the parent (`tmr_box`) instead.

Comment: That was actually the problem, I didn't notice. Thanks mate